# Didn't existed or hadn't existed?

Tags: verb-forms, negation, perfect-constructions, do-support

I come across this in todays New Yorker:

Birkenstocks, like an iPad, or an eight-dollar bottle of cold-pressed juice, are the covetable answer to a need that **hadn’t existed** before they came along.

Isn't this just a past tense and shouldn't be written as: Didn't existed ?
Would that be wrong?

Comment: Recommended reading: [How and when should I use the perfect?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13262/3281)

Comment: *Didn't exist* would work.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't such a thing as "Didn't existed". Past tense would be: "Didn't exist".

> **Example**: It didn't exist yesterday.

If something was done in the past before another event happened, then the correct form would be: "Hadn't existed"

> **Example**: It hadn't existed before they came along. But then they came along and put it into existence.

:)

Answer (score 1):

The negative past tense it's made with *didn't* + base form, where the base form is the infinitive without *to.*
 The **past perfect** is used when an action or event happened before than other action in the past.

> *I was hungry because I hadn't eaten anything.*